# Implementing a generic interface for any type in a concrete class in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I want to do something like the following

```
    public abstract class StaticValue : IRefDynamicValue<RefT>
    {
        public abstract int get();

        public int get(RefT refValue)
        {
            return get();
        }
    }

    public interface IRefDynamicValue<RefT> 
    {
        public int get(RefT refValue);
    }
```

In my specific case, I'm making a game where I have `IRefDynamicValue<Actor>`, `IRefDynamicValue<Ability>`, etc., but I want `StaticValue` (basically just an int) to be able to serve as any of them (for example an ability parameter).

In general though, the situation is that I have a concrete type that I want to be able to implement a generic interface for any type because it just ignores and never uses the type parameter.

The code above of course isn't possible in C#.  Is there a different way to implement this kind of relationship in C#, either through some other trick with generics or just an alternate code structure?

Comment: Not sure but maybe StaticValue : IRefDynamicValue<object> is what you need

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the second paragraph, could you explain further ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `IRefDynamicValue<object>`, and make `IRefDynamicValue` contravariant:

```
public abstract class StaticValue : IRefDynamicValue<object>

// and also:
public interface IRefDynamicValue<in RefT>
```

Now you can do:

```
IRefDynamicValue<Actor> x = someStaticValue;
```

Note that this doesn't work for `RefT`s that are value types.

Comment: This seems to be an extremely backward way of getting this to compile. I can't see how this helps the OP?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need this:

```
public abstract class StaticValue : IRefDynamicValue
{
    public abstract int get();

    public int get<RefT>(RefT refValue)
    {
        return get();
    }
}

public interface IRefDynamicValue
{
    public int get<RefT>(RefT refValue);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't allow me to specify that I want dynamic values of only a specific type, and it doesn't allow me to create classes that implement the interface for a specific type.

For example, let's say I want to make

```
public class Ability
{
     List<IRefDynamicValue<Ability>> modifiers
}

public class NumTargets: IRefDynamicValue<Ability>
{
         public int get(Ability ability) { ...}
}
```

I want to restrict an ability to only have ability dynamic values, and it doesn't make sense to get the numTargets for an Actor.

Comment: @stackedAE - What does "dynamic values of only a specific type" mean? How is it that the accepted answer actually helps here?